# Replace one or more sub-strings from multiple file names in a folder

Tags: pandas, glob, renaming

I have a list of files for which I would like to replace a substring within their name. The `glob.glob(path)` returns:

```
'./path\\2016_Joe_Black_tall_blond',
etc.
```

where `Joe_Black` should become `Joe-Black`.
I would have to do the same for other names, e.g. `Tim_Blue` becomes `Tim-Blue` etc.
(can I gather all those into `names=[Joe_Black, Tim_Blue ...]` ?)

I have found multiple approaches online, but what would be the best to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for this purpose. In this example, I simply replace `_` by `-`. Note `basename` is used to extract the name of the file and not its full path.

```
import glob
import os

path = "./data/"
# Make list of paths
names = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*")) 
# Returning a list of file names (without path) where a character is replaced
names = [os.path.basename(name).replace('_', '-') for name in names]
```